# stylesheet is not being used in asp.net masterpage

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have the following code in the project's MasterPage.master file :

<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("System").ToString() %>

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Stylesheets" runat="server">
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="/App_Data/Styles/Site.css" type="text/css" />
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

<%
    If (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Mode").ToString() = "TEST") Then
%>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background: #99cccc;
    }
</style>
<%
End If
%>
```

I do not want to do this:

```
<%--<div style="text-align:center">--%>
```

rather I want to be able to do this:

```
<div class="masterpagediv">
```

The CSS file contains:

```
.masterpagediv {
    text-align: center;
}
```

I am not sure if the location of the CSS us being correctly identified in the href which could be the reason that the rule is not being applied to the  tag.

The project did not use CSS before I started working with it.  Am I supposed to enable something to be able to use the CSS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your other styling work?

Try setting the background color on the class to make sure it's being applied to what you want.

From the markup you posted, there's no div with that class applied. You may want to double check that you're applying the style in the tag.

One more thing that just got me the other day - I had to set the CSS MIME type up in IIS. There's no error when this happens, you just won't get styling. Otherwise IIS doesn't know how to serve the file. (Strange, I know, but true)

Comment: The body background styling does work as the page color is what i indicate (#99cccc).

I am running this application from Visual Studio on my desktop and I have not had the same problem w/other projects.

What do you mean by this : "From the markup you posted, there's no div with that class applied."

Comment: Again, I am also concerned over the location of the CSS file.  When running the project using IE, if I click on Developer Tools, I see that the CSS file is expected to be in "http://localhost/App_Data/Styles/Site.css" but I am not sure that that location is correct.

Comment: @user3258904 - Your embedded style is working, but the CSS in App_Data isn't working. Try moving the CSS to a different folder. (I believe App_Data is a special folder for databases, so it can't serve anything like a CSS file)

Comment: Thanks Tim! I put the CSS under "Content" folder and now my references to the CSS contents work.